# Can Nietzsche's overman be thought of as a centripetal force?

Tags: nietzsche, history

Can Nietzsche's overman be thought of as a centripetal force?

> Centripetal is an adjective describing a force that brings things
>   toward the center, not unlike the force of a black hole. Centripetal
>   is often confused with the word centrifugal. They may begin the same
>   way, but they mean the exact opposite.

I like the idea of opposing forces at work, in this way.

Can it be? Might that help me understand his ideal?

Comment: Could you explain less metaphorically what "mapping Nietzshe's overman as a centripetal force" means? By the way, the idea of "opposing forces at work" does not work with this metaphor. The [centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) is fictitious, the centripetal force actually "works" against the body's own inertia, not against another force. I suppose, Nietzshe would have liked the idea of working against own inertia, but then any force does that, not necessarily centripetal.

Comment: @Conifold what do you mean less metaphorically(not being sarcastic, i just am unsure what you're asking for)? thanks for the physics comment (?) but it's a metaphor, so not sure that it matters?

Comment: It is unclear to me what "overman as a centripetal force" means in a philosophical context, this can be interpreted in any number of ways, and you do not say what you have in mind beyond the phrase itself. So unless someone used those exact words, "overman as a centripetal force", it is unclear how to answer your question. And even if someone did it may not be what you mean. Also, "Dependent on 'history', how that works..." sentence is perplexing, what does it mean?

Comment: As I see it, the notion of the overman does nothing to contain anything or anyone or bring them together.  If anything, it is the opposite -- a genuinely centrifugal force.  The overman would be less like another overman than any man is like another man.  The opposing concept is 'the herd', which allows society to enclose them and hold them together, and one of the defining characteristics of the overman is to not be subject to that force.

Comment: @jobermark thanks for the comment, ofc. @ conifold, the history comment is meant to be the enlightening component ha. all that time, spent...

Comment: I'm also incredibly confused as to what the "Dependent on 'history'" sentence means. Why are you putting it in quotes, what significance does using it in quotes have? I am sure that it makes sense to you but it is not evident to anyone else who reads it. Are you saying you're skeptical of the concept of history, are you saying that history is untrustworthy? I don't think there's enough context for other people to understand what that sentence means.

Comment: @Not_Here cool, if it's not self evident i'll elide in case of ppp

Comment: @idiotan I have no idea what that comment means but it sounds like you took what i said negatively. I'm just trying to help you make the question more clearly stated so that somebody will answer it. If you feel like this question states exactly what you are asking then, of course, you're under no obligation to make any edits.

Comment: @Not_Here "ppp" is 'puhsing a personal philosophy" hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually turns out to be a general philosophy lesson, more than anything specific on Nietzsche.  The real answer is "The overman can be thought of as a centripetal force if that analogy works well."  You have to flesh the analogy out before any statement can be made.

In this case, Nietzsche's Übermensch is a tremendously complicated multi-faceted ideal.  Comparing it to a centripetal force is like saying the Christian God can be thought of as a triangle.  You are welcome to make the comparison, but you actually have to make it.  You have to explain why its useful to think of it as a centripetal force.  Likewise, thinking of the Christian God as the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit has value to some, and thinking of it as a triangle could have value.  But in both cases, the analogy is comparing to something far simpler than the original, so you really have to explain why the comparison is valuable enough to a listener.

You say "[you] like the idea of opposing forces at work."  In that case, flesh the idea out and see what these opposing forces are.  See if the imagery inspires a deeper understanding of the Übermensch.  If it does, great!  If not, then don't force the Übermensch into a particular shape.

Comment: well, this answers the question, trivially and or with  a platidude, but admirably, as it stands